# Get all the android application category by query

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

queryIntentActivities.... im using this to get all the install apps in android but now i want to categorized the application just look like in the yahoo aviate launcher.

display the application in to general category like Entertainment, Social, Game etc

Comment: Look at this may be a good starting point https://developers.google.com/drive/android/appfolder and https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/

Comment: but i have already get the install app and their relative info. but i never seen any info about application Category. so is there nay way to get the category of the application from PackageManager